# How can a sound bar play sound with single optical ports multiple devices?

Tags: hdmi, 4k, sound-system, blu-ray

I want to keep hold of my current 42” smart hd tv for now and buy a 4K / blu ray / 3D / hdr player and a sound bar.

My tv has an audio optical input.

My blu ray player has an audio optical output which I plug into my tv, it also has connectors and speakers.

I’ve looked at sound bars and 4K players and they both have a single audio optical port.

I want to still be able to watch stuff on my smart tv apps (Netflix etc). And from my Apple TV.

So not just watch I want to use these with the sound bar and a new player.

So my question is how will my tv smart apps, Apple TV and 4K player play sound through a sound bar if one device doesn’t have 2 audio optical ports?

Comment: I find it unusual that your TV has an optical **in** port. They usually have one optical out. Can you confirm that info please? Your Blu-Ray also player sounds like it has an integrated speaker system too. That would mean it has an optical **input** and your TV has an optical **output**.

Comment: Yes your correct tv has optical output 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect everything up through HDMI, it should work fine. I myself only use one optical connection from my TV to my receiver, because my receiver pre-dates HDMI. So the audio data from my PS4 goes through HDMI to the TV which passes it through the TOS-link to the receiver. I haven't encountered any problems with codecs. All codecs that the receiver supports work and otherwise it just falls back to PCM channels.

So in short, I don't think you will even need optical connections, since you are buying them all new.